# Why is the space of linear operators to a Banach Space complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-explanation, banach-spaces

I know this has been answered before, but I wanted to understand a particular proof. We have a space X and a Banach Space Y. We take a sequence of bounded linear operators from X to Y i.e. $T_n$ which is Cauchy. Then we have $\forall x \in X$ and $\epsilon >0$ there is such a N that for $n, m >N$: $||T_n(x)-T_m(x)||_Y < \epsilon ||x||$. Hence we have a Cauchy sequence in Y, which converges by completeness of Y.

We define $T(x) = \lim_n T_n(x)$.

This is then clearly well defined and linear. We need to show that T is bounded. I have seen many proofs for why this is bounded. One of them is:

> We note that
> $$
> \left\|T_{n} x\right\|_{\gamma} \leq\left\|T_{n}\right\|\|x\|_{X}
> $$
> and $\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}}|| T_{n} \|<\infty$ by the Cauchy property of the sequence of the operators. Hence, we get
> $$
> \|T x\|_{Y} \leq \sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}}\left\|T_{n}\right\| \cdot\|x\|_{X}
> $$

I understand that $\sup _{n \in \mathbb{N}}|| T_{n} \|<\infty$ because all Cauchy sequences are bounded, but in the last line why can we take the limit inside? Is it because $T_n(x)$ is a convergent sequence in Y and $||.||$ is continuous, hence we can take the limit inside of the norm to get what we have written?

Comment: Yes, that is precisely why we can take limit inside.

Comment: That is the reason. But where does the $\sup$ come from, since we have taken the limit... . I would have rather written $\displaystyle \lVert Tx \rVert_Y \leq \liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \lVert T_n \rVert \cdot \lVert x \rVert_X$. The $\liminf$ is of course still bounded.